# gstreamer axis camera

Tags: camera, gstreamer

I have a rtsp web stream (axis 211 ip camera).  Gst-launch Playbin2 uri=... can show it just fine.  I cannot figure out the right pipeline to duplicate what playbin2 is doing.  Is there a way to dump a description of the pipeline playbin 2 creates.

Answer (score 1):

You should first identify the type streams outputted by the camera. For example I have axis 1054 camera transmitting h.264 video and MPEG-4 AAC audio (.m4a) elementary streams.

So my pipeline for displaying the video is as follows:-

```
gst-launch rtspsrc location = rtsp://192.x.x.x:555/media ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink.
```

If you are identifying the format of the streams correctly then you should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

use the -v argument to gst-launch. You can figure out what pieces to put together from the output.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer were useful for sure but in the end I found the bast way is to use the DOT file dump.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/DumpingPipelineGraphs

you can see al the details of what the playbin constructed..  Very useful.

In a C program you can call

[GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE()](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstInfo.html#GST-DEBUG-BIN-TO-DOT-FILE%3aCAPS)